# Matplotlib - matching axes unit length (resolution)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to match the resolution of x- and y-axes in matplotlib, so that the linear function `y=x` would plot as an exactly 45° line, and so that a mathematically plotted circle (`r^2=x^2+y^2`) would appear round.

This because I'm plotting geographical data, and would like a given distance measured along the x-axis to equal the distance measured along the y-axis. I'm rather new to MatPlotLib, and have problems finding the answer in the documentation.

**Edit:** This could be accomplished by manually setting an pixels-per-unit-ratio for both axes. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with [`axes.set_aspect`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect). For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = plt.figure()
x = f.gca()
x.set_aspect("equal")
x.plot(range(10),range(10))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, I just figured it out, and was about to add an answer on my own :-) `x.set_aspect("equal")`, or `sp = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect="equal")` when creating a subplot, does the trick.